# Node.js 502 Bad Gateway on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http-status-code-502

I deployed my node.js server on AWS. Server works well. But when I work on website sometimes it gives "502 bad  gateway" error. And when I reload page, it works well again. How to fix it?

After 502 error in new logs I found this:

[image]

Comment: Read the logs for your service. That's really the only way to know what's happening.

Comment: @AKX I check logs, update on question.

Comment: Your program gets terminated with SIGTERM. You would probably need system logs to figure out why.